# TexLive can't find newtxtext.sty

Tags: latex, tex-live

I have an installation of TexLive and I just downloaded my uni template for papers. For now I'm just trying to make it compile by installing all the dependencies, but I got stuck at newtxtext, because I have newtx installed from the TexLive Shell, and I can find the newtxtext.sty file at `"C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\newtx\newtxtext.sty"`, but when I try to compile the pdf from TeXStudio it gives me `File 'newtxtext.sty' not found.`

I didn't try much because I have no idea what to try. I would try to compile it from the command line but I don't know how to do it since this project has many files

Here is the whole log file:
[Log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-9OPWJjYWAKHkKv7duw-vEuf7upZ6kcS6KBXZ2cn2go/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: To compile the document from the command line you can use `pdflatex mainfile.tex` from the folder of the main file (replace `mainfile.tex` with the name of your main file).

Comment: Can you share your .log file? My first guess that you might have 2 tex installations and texstudio picks up the other one.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz added the log, but I am almost sure that I have only one installation